# Apple numbers: How can I create a filtered column (B) with only unique values from column (A)?

Tags: spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

I'm using Apple Numbers.

I have a table with data like:

```
 A       | B
---------+---------
Spain    |
U.K      |
Spain    |
Germany  |
U.K      |
Italy    |
```

And I would like to set table B to include only the unique values from table A

```
 A       | B
---------+---------
Spain    | Spain
U.K      | U.K
Spain    | Germany
Germany  | Italy
U.K      |
Italy    |
```

I've found [this solution](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/#unique) `=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))`
 which seems to work in Microsoft Xcel and Google Sheets, but not in Numbers.

In Numbers, the MATCH() function throws an error because the set `$B$1:B1` won't contain any `0` values if there's a duplicate.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Not a good sign for Numbers that this question wasn't answered immediately, let alone 3 years later. You'd think this should be standard functionality for a spreadsheet app.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8420379?answerId=33497580022#33497580022) by user Barry to the question ["Need distinct list from a column"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8420379) on Apple's Support Communities describes a way to accomplish this in Numbers.app:

[image: Table 1 (left) with values and Table 2 (right) with unique values]
*Table 1 (left) with values and Table 2 (right) with unique values.*



Table 1 contains one formula, entered in D2:

```
D2: IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C2,C2)=1,MAX(D$1:D1)+1,"")
```

Table 2 contains 2 formulas, entered in A2 and B2:

```
A2: IF(ROW()−1>MAX(Table 1::D),"",INDEX(Table 1::C,MATCH(ROW()−1,Table 1::D,0)))

B2: COUNTIF(Table 1::C,A2)
```

Drag Down to fill the formulas in all rows. The index column can then be hidden.

Comment: In table 1, are there any reason why you have a col A and B?

Comment: I think they can be omitted and the formulas adjusted accordingly.